# Http Post request Without encoding parameters in C# Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, post, windows-phone-8.1

I have made a post request with comma separated values. But my form contents changes and "," replace with "%2C". So request does not receive at server side.

I just want to replace "%2C" with ",".

I tried with different codes but that code are for string.

```
   //Uri.EscapeDataString(formContent).Replace("%2C", ",");
```

Above line is for string but I need same for FormContent.

Here is my Code.

```
         Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient clientOb = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
         Uri connectionUrl = new Uri("http://www.helloworld.com/istar/fileupload/Lip?");

        string framURL = UTCdatetime + "," + lng + "," + lat + "," + speed  + alt + "," + "," + battery_level + "," + accuracy;





        Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pairs.Add("name", Image_file_name);
        pairs.Add("frame", framURL);

       //Here is My Content Form. 
       Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
```

I'm getting FormContent  encoded. like

```
  {name=WP_20160224_002.jpg&frame=927858b101b71083f37549517819d6ac%2C20160225125928%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C100%2C%2C2%2C%2C%2C0}
```

I need to send request with Comma's so I want to remove "%2C". Please help out in this problem.

I Required above contentform like this...

```
   {name=WP_20160224_002.jpg&frame=927858b101b71083f37549517819d6ac,20160225092908,74.253794,31.471193,-1,-1,0,,100,103,2,-1,0}
```

Here I send post request.

```
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await clientOb.PostAsync(connectionUrl, formContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing form encoding with URL encoding. Given your example, there's little need to encode this query string. Forms and query strings have a similar `key=value` syntax, but there are differences in format.

You're right to use the Uri class - but you can wait until the very end to construct it from a string, as this will ensure the given string is fully sanitized - see the remarks section of [MSDN documentation of Uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's an untested example:

```
string framURL = UTCdatetime + "," + lng + "," + lat + "," + speed  + alt + "," + "," + battery_level + "," + accuracy;
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pairs.Add("name", Image_file_name);
pairs.Add("frame", framURL);
var queryString = String.Join("&", pairs.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value));
Uri connectionUrl = new Uri("http://www.helloworld.com/istar/fileupload/Lip?" + queryString);
```

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: I got the exact url in  connectionUrl     .. Now need to post this url..   Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await clientOb.PostAsync(connectionUrl, formContent);      this method always take 2 parameter with form type and url type...

Comment: Wait, you were trying to compose a form body in the first place? What is the endpoint expecting? Should these data be passed in a querystring or as form content?

Comment: Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await clientOb.PostAsync(connectionUrl, formContent);    This string as it is sends the data at server. But I have to send form Content with this... while I have complete URI string...

Comment: What are you meant to send in the form content? And what are you meant to send in the query string? Your explanation is confusing.